# Office 2013 activation of different machine

Tags: microsoft-office-2013

I've installed Office Professional Plus 2013 on my machine, but it was installed via a downloader from Microsoft.  As soon as I ran the downloader it immediately started installing it in the background.  It wasn't my intention to install it on my machine; I wanted to step through the installer so I could help a family member over the phone install it on her machine.

The installer never asked me for a product key but it did ask me to sign in with a Microsoft account.  I did NOT sign in.

**If I uninstall it from my machine, can it be installed on my family member's machine and activated with the product key without any licensing trouble?**

Comment: Just uninstall it from your machine once you do that it can be activate on your family members machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installer and activation are two separate processes.  You can use the installer as many times as you want, on as many machines as you want.  Once you *run* Office, it will go through the activation process.

Comment: That's what I figured.  Just wanted to make double-sure.  I'm still used to the old way, where the product key ask required before installation finishes.  Thanks!